How does pandas isna treat pd.NA?
I have the following dataframe
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0,   0,      0],
    'b': [0, 1, 2.3, np.nan],
}).astype('Float64')

that I need to apply an operation on each row
a_nan = a.apply(lambda a:a/a.mean())
This results in the following dataframe
     a         b
0  NaN       0.0
1  NaN  0.909091
2  NaN  2.090909
3  NaN      <NA>

I then need to find all nan/null values, so I try isna()
a_nan.isna()
But I get
       a      b
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False   True

This also happens with isnull. Why does this happen?
Just to be clear, I know how to fix the problem, I just don't understand why isna does not remove pd.NA .
Also, if I convert the dataframe's type to object or float64 (with a lowercase ´f´) then isna outputs.
print(a_nan.astype('object').isna())
      a      b
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
3  True   True
print(a_nan.astype('float64').isna())
      a      b
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
3  True   True

Here's the example code I'm using.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [0, 0,   0,      0],
    'b': [0, 1, 2.3, np.nan],
}).astype('Float64')
a_nan = a.apply(lambda a:a/a.mean())
print(a_nan)
print(a_nan.isna())
print(a_nan.isnull())
print(a_nan.astype('object').isna())


Looks like a bug to me

@mozway, I just found this related issue GH53887. From what I understand, isnull (alias of isna) can't handle yet (or anymore) Series with an extension dtype like Float64 and that's applies to OP since a_nan.dtypes shows a Float64Dtype().

You can try pd.isna.... a_nan.map(pd.isna)

Let's use pd.isna method:
a_nan.map(pd.isna)

Output:
      a      b
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
3  True   True

